# BigCommerce - Stencil - client configurable text value pair

Tags: bigcommerce

Working on a Stencil theme that supports a third-party javascript widget.  No problem passing product data to the script.  The problem is I need to pass the client's license key and don't want to hardcode it in a template.  The schema.json does not support a text field.  Any idea how a store owner can set text configuration that is accessible via a yaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question Stencil has implemented this feature.

[Object Structure in schema.json: Text Examples](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/schemajson-metadata-for-theme-editor#schema-json-text)

Answer (score 1):

Any reason setting the value in the config.json file and calling it into the template wouldn't work?

You would set this value in your config file like so.

```
"settings": {
   "my_license_key": "abcdefg",
   ....
}
```

Then call your value in a template.

```
<p>{{theme_settings.my_license_key}}</p>
```

This way you wouldn't need to include the YAML attribute on each page you need the value either.

Comment: This happens to be my current approach but does not allow the client to set the value.  As far as I understand this means packaging a new theme to change this value.

Comment: On which pages do you need to define this value?

Comment: Depending on the integration this could be required on any page.  I'm looking for a general mechanism to address this need.  To that end, I do not see how a particular page would matter.

Comment: Would the additional scripts area of BigCommerce work? https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Adding-Custom-Scripts-to-Stencil-Themes . This injects the scripts into the footer of each page. Other than that, I'm not aware of other options for defining admin area values and calling them in your templates. I've gotten away using some simple workarounds for promo text, or image swapping using marketing blocks, and blog posts, but they are not very flexible and usually require the client be capable of editing HTML.

Comment: Interesting idea to use gobal Javascript variables set via "Adding Custom Scripts to Stencil Themes"  Thanks for the feedback.